# Sinatra on Rails '/' mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sinatra

I might be missing something but how can I map "/" in Rails to execute the Sinatra application? I have:

```
class Core < Sinatra::Base

 get '/' do
  "This is root but it is caput."
 end

 get '/test' do
  "This is test and it works"
 end

end
```

So if I do routing like that:

```
match '/test' => Core
match '/'=>Core
```

only '/test' fires Sinatra app '/' runs the Rails. Actually I want every route to be handled by Sinatra app.

Comment: What does this have to do with Rails exactly?

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you remove `index.html` from the public folder? :)

Comment: Thank you @padde. Removing index.html worked.

Comment: @kwicher: Then please accept my answer, so other people facing this problem can find a quick solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove `index.html` from the `public` folder.

You can mount the whole app with `mount Core, :at => '/'` in order to let Sinatra do all the routing.

Comment: What if I need to all requests to be processed by Sinatra. Do I need to map each single one in routes.rb with matching sinatra ones.

Comment: I must admit that i never used Sinatra with Rails, but when you want all routes to be processed by Sinatra, why not just set up a plain Sinatra app?

Comment: That is the problem. I need to transfer my Sinatra app to the ISP which does not allow to run Sinatra as a standalone app but I can run Rails.

Comment: Maybe a simple `match "/*" => Core` will do?

Comment: I thought about it but rails app crashes during startup if I include the line in routes.rb

Comment: Try adding a named parameter as a workaround `match "/page*" => Core`

Comment: How about a new question with detailed error message and you full routes.rb?

Comment: I found the solution. In routes.rb, I just put `mount Core, :at => '/'`.

Comment: Nice. If its ok with you, i'll put it also in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Sinatra creates a DSL for defining routes (that are not accessible directly as methods), you'll probably need to add a helper method so you can specifically invoke the route:
i.e.

```
  def launch_sinatra_app
    status, headers, body = call env.merge("PATH_INFO" => '/')
    [status, headers, body.map(&:upcase)] # proper rack response
  end
```

and then in config/routes.rb for rails:

```
match :root => 'Core#launch_sinatra_app'
```